# href link not working

Tags: php, href

I'm learning PHP from a book and I copied the code below from the book site.  When I run it in Zend Studio and select any of the hyperlinks eg *Home*, all that's displayed is the name of the php file.  For example *index.php*. It does not link to and execute the php file. Why is that?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
    <?php
     session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Class Registration Template</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "C:\Users\trevor.reeves\Documents\PHP&mySQLBook\php-mysql-abg-listings-1\ClassRegistration_Public/registration.css"/>
        <script type= "text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="C:\Users\trevor.reeves\Documents\PHP&mySQLBook\php-mysql-abg-listings-1\ClassRegistration_Public/MatTechLogo.gif" alt="Matthews Technology" />
                <h1 id="title">Class Selection and Registration</h1>

            </div> <!-- id="header" -->
            <div id="hnav">
                <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                  <tr>
                    <td><a class="hmenu" href="index.php">Home</a> </td>
                    <td><a href="index.php">About</a> </td>
                    <td><a href="index.php">Support</a> </td>
                    <td><a href="/AdministratorAuthentication/adminAuthen.php">Maintain</a> </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

            </div> <!-- id="hnav" -->
            <div id="vnav">
                <table width="120" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="vhead">Go To: </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="classlist.php">Class List</a> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="nameentry.php">Student Entry</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div> <!-- id="vnav" -->
            <div id="main">
                <h1 id="maintitle">Spring Class Schedule</h1>
                <p id="mainpara">Click Register to do so for a class.</p>
                <p class="red">*A footnote.</p>

            </div> <!-- id="main" -->
            <div id="footer">
                <p id="copyright">
                    Copyright &copy:2008 -
                    <?php
                         date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');
                         echo date('Y');
                    ?>
                    Matthews Technology
                </p>
                <p id="contact">
                     <a href="mailto:info@matthewstechnology.com">Contact us by clicking here.</a>
                </p>
            </div> <!-- id="footer" -->
        </div> <!-- id="wrapper" -->

        <?php
         ;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you installed XAMPP or WAMPP for php rendering.

Comment: Why are link reference pointing to absolute path in your local drive ? **stylesheet** and **img** reference should point to relative path or http(s) path

Comment: Side tip:if you are trying to learn never copy code rather type it.

Comment: I dont understand the problem. Can you emphasize?

Comment: CodeGodie: when I execute the code listed, called template.php, and click on the hyperlink Home or Maintain, Zend does not execute those php files.  It merely displays the name of the files instead and does nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the file reference your disk operating system using to access the files. You need to use the reference your server is using. Normally it would be localhost/directory/filename.php localhost will point to the location your server tells it to point to, which is located in you php.ini file.

Comment: It will be labeled document_root.

Comment: I've tried absolute operating system reference, the server reference (localhost/....), and also relative reference. All do the same thing: just display the php file name. :|

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help., esp. kayleighsdaddy.